# PHP remote database access with plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have been developing a plugin for Wordpress and I am stuck at point where I have to connect my plugin to a database remotely.
I know the procedural way of estabilishing the connection to a database which looks something like this `$link = mysqli_connect("hostname", "username", "password", "database");`
The `$link` variable will either return true or false depending on connection status, in my case the plugin is not allowed to connect to my MySQL server due to Administrator restrictions.

I have few questions regarding this.

1. What do you do in cases like these? If one enables the access via MySQL dashboard on a single database to make the connection, would that make a database vulnerable to injections or less protected?
2. If the previous is the right way, how do you pass the parameters properly to a function without revealing the plain credentials?
3. Is there any other way to implement this logic to get the needed data that plugin requires?

P.S. I have already tried looking up here for an answer without luck, the PHP documentation also did not help.

Comment: 1. If you use such code for a remote db connection then it is vulnerable to SQL injection and it is lot more easy to get credentials of your db. 2 You must use encryption for db credentials. Or 3 you can use key, secret pair to get a connection to fb. Besides all these you need to secure you php file being access easily.

Comment: Remote hostnames are perfectly fine, as are read-only accounts or limited views. The alternative is devising an API on your remote server instead. If this is for some licensing/obfuscation bonkum, don't waste everyones time.

Comment: mario I am well aware these type of questions aren't meant for stack, it's just I dont have anyone to ask.
And full_stack_developer, thank you both, I will come up with a solution with given advices hopefully.